# The project you are opening contains compilation error Unity

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

**при первой установки юнити через unity hub** у меня возникла ошибка, но я решил проблему установив его через официальный сайт, теперь же, когда я пытаюсь **запустить новый проект**, возникает такая проблема:
[image: скриншот ошибки]

пробовал искать ответ проблемы на данном форуме, но это никчему не привело, да и в интернете ничего не нашел, так что буду очень благодарен, если вы поможете мне!

Comment: Игнорируйте. У вас в каком-то скрипте есть ошибки. Можете посмотреть тут: https://forum.unity.com/threads/somebody-please-help.1032322/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте ПОЛНОСТЬЮ удалить и заново [установить](https://unity3d.com/ru/get-unity/download) с официального сайта  Unity. Рекомендую скачать Unity hub и с него установить данную версию(не рекомендую качать бета версии).
Возможно у вас при установке произошла ошибка, или когда вы запускаете проект не до конца его загружаете(нажимаете отмена).